# Fliker .Net API Connection Error

Tags: c#, .net, api

did use the fliker api in my website but when it run the following code it is giving the error

> "{"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}"

```
        Flickr flickr = new Flickr(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shardSecret"]);

        return flickr.PhotosetsGetList(userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Flicker API now works on **HTTPS**. Please make sure you have passed

```
    https://www.flickr.com
```

There could even problem with your KEYS or it might be ;

- 403.1 - Execute access forbidden.
- 403.2 - Read access forbidden.
- 403.3 - Write access forbidden.
- 403.4 - SSL required.
- 403.5 - SSL 128 required.
- 403.6 - IP address rejected.
- 403.7 - Client certificate required.
- 403.8 - Site access denied.
- 403.9 - Too many users.
- 403.10 - Invalid configuration.
- 403.11 - Password change.
- 403.12 - Mapper denied access.
- 403.13 - Client certificate revoked.
- 403.14 - Directory listing denied.
- 403.15 - Client Access Licenses exceeded.
- 403.16 - Client certificate is untrusted or invalid.
- 403.17 - Client certificate has expired or is not yet valid.

Comment: i did give the correct key. do you have any sample which work fine,if you can share plz

Comment: i did download the fliker .net api from there website